# Display public PowerBI report with powerbi.js (without credentials / token)

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-js-api

I'm trying to embed a PowerBI report in my webpage

This code works well WHEN the report has been published on Azure. So, providing the good credentials, everything is OK

```
var config = {
            type: 'report',
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            embedUrl: embedUrl,
            id: embedReportId,
            permissions: models.Permissions.All,
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: true,
                navContentPaneEnabled: true
            }
        };

        // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
        var reportContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
        // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
        window.powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
```

However, I have some PUBLIC reports.
Absolutely anyone can access them with the url and I'd like to display them the same way I did for "private" reports.

I know I could just do something like :

```
<iframe src="https://my-public-url" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

But I'd like to know if (and how ?) I could use the `window.powerbi.embed` method, providing it an object saying : "here is the my-custom-url for the report, but there's no need for token or id, just get it and display it".
Obviously, if `accessToken` or `id` is null, then nothing is shown...

I've found [the very same question here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-embed-public-reports-using-Javascript-API/td-p/869501), but non-answered

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: No, publish to web is completely different method and Power BI JavaScript client can't be used to load such reports. You must authenticate with valid credentials and acquire a token to use this kind of embedding.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov  So how can I embed such a public report ? Only with `<iframe src="my-url" />` ??

Comment: If it is yours, then use your credentials embed the original report (not the published URL) using the JS client. If it is not yours, then you can't do much - only what is allowed by the report's author, which in this case is to use the iframe code given to you.